# Analytics service-to-service google-auth-library-nodejs

Tags: node.js, google-analytics, google-authentication

Referencing this doc [JSON Web Tokens](https://github.com/google/google-auth-library-nodejs#json-web-tokens), I have tried to access the Analytics Reporting API, trying first "Application Default Credentials" then "JSON Web Tokens" authentication.
Each time I receive the error `Request had insufficient authentication scopes.`

I have no problem accessing the data through [Query Explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/), and I really don't want to use OAuth2, since I would only ever be accessing my own account to begin with. The scopes listed below were derived from "Google Analytics API, v3" in [Google scopes](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes).

Given the error message, I've tried various iterations of other scopes, most notably those for "Analytics Reporting API, v4."
**Note**: the email provided in the service account key from the Google Developers Console has been added to all permissions (account, property, view) of the Analytics Admin Console. I have also tried something similar as described in "[Service <--> Service authentication](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/#service-to-service-authentication)".

Attempting "Application Default Credentials" (setting path to service account key in .env):

```
const {auth} = require('google-auth-library');
async function main() {
  const client = await auth.getClient({
    scopes: [
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics',
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.edit',
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.manage.users',
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.manage.users.readonly',
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.provision',
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly',
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.user.deletion'
    ]
  });
  const projectId = await auth.getProjectId();
  const url = `https://www.googleapis.com/dns/v1/projects/${projectId}`;
  const res = await client.request({ url });
  console.log(res.data);
}
main().catch(console.error);
```

Attempting "JSON Web Tokens:"

```
const {JWT} = require('google-auth-library');
const keys = require('../service-account-credentials.json');

async function main() {
  console.log('keys.client_email: ', keys.client_email)
  console.log('keys.private_key: ', keys.private_key)
  const client = new JWT(
    keys.client_email,
    null,
    keys.private_key,
    [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.edit',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.manage.users',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.manage.users.readonly',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.provision',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.user.deletion'
    ],
  );
  const url = `https://www.googleapis.com/dns/v1/projects/${keys.project_id}`;
  const res = await client.request({url});
  console.log(res.data);
  const tokenInfo = await client.getTokenInfo(client.credentials.access_token);
  console.log(tokenInfo);
}

main().catch(console.error);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url specified in the boilerplate example needs to be replaced with the analytics query, such as that from ["API Query URI"](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/).

For example, if I want number of page views, I would replace the url used in the question's snippet:

`https://www.googleapis.com/dns/v1/projects/${projectId}`

with that specified in the Query Explorer:

`https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga%${analyticsViewOrProfileId}&start-date=30daysAgo&end-date=2018-08-28&metrics=ga%3Apageviews&dimensions=ga%3ApagePath&sort=-ga%3Apageviews`

The resulting (functioning) code is as follows:

```
const {auth} = require('google-auth-library');

async function main() {
  const client = await auth.getClient({
    scopes: [
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics',
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'
    ]
  });
  const viewId = <VIEW ID FROM ANALYTICS CONSOLE>
  const url = `https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga%3A${viewId}&start-date=30daysAgo&end-date=2018-08-28&metrics=ga%3Apageviews&dimensions=ga%3ApagePath&sort=-ga%3Apageviews`;
  const res = await client.request({ url });
  console.log(res.data);
}
main().catch(console.error);
```